# MongoMapper OR clause on 2 columns - Rails 3.1.rc4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

How to perform something like this:

```
User.where("private = 1 OR beta = 0")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or

That translates to:

```
User.where(:$or => [{:private => 1}, {:beta => 0}])
```

Comment: This is not working unfortunately. Its simply doing the AND operation right now.. I will investigate further and update here. Thank you very much for looking into it :-)