# Query is not executing in rails app using mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

In my rails application i am writing mongo db query to collections where it should perform AND operation **(Example: Basically i want all the user details from collection where city=delhi and gender=male)**.I am stuck in this ,  I am referring to this link . http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html. Even i have followed the below links [MongoMapper OR clause on 2 columns - Rails 3.1.rc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175328/mongomapper-or-clause-on-2-columns-rails-3-1-rc4). But nothing is working, I am new to this i dont know is this correct approach or else is there any methods,  kindly help me out in this.

I am using rails 3.1 and mongo_mapper ORM.

query details :

`@c=Customer.where(:$and => [:gender => "Male",:city => "DELHI/NCR"])`

```
Output: #<Plucky::Query $and: [{:gender=>"Male", :city=>"DELHI/NCR"}], transformer: #<Proc:0xe6429b4@/home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongo_mapper-0.11.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:79 (lambda)>>
```

I have tried this also nothing is working

`@c=Customer.where(:$and => [{:gender => "Male"},{:city => "DELHI/NCR"}])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you use it it would only create the query, you will need to 'execute' it by appending .all

```
@customers = Customer.where(:gender => "Male", :city => "DELHI/NCR").all
```

read more on it here: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html#criteria

Comment: but how to make use of $and ,$or operations?

Comment: if you have a comma separated list AND is implied, to get the same query as OR it would be 
   @customers = Customer.where('$or' => [{:gender => 'Male'},{:city => 'DELHI/NCR'}]).all

Comment: for more advanced queries read up here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries

Comment: Customer.where('$or' => [{:gender => 'Male'},{:city => 'DELHI/NCR'}]).all  this query is not working ??

Comment: could you try :$or instead of '$or'? Both work here but I might have a slightly older version of mongomapper

Answer (score 1):

```
@c = Customer.where(:gender => "Male",:city => "DELHI/NCR").all
```

Comment: but how to make use of $and ,$or operations?

Comment: example of using, where gender male and city DELHI/NCR or Noida/NCR   @c = Customer.where(:gender => 'Male', '$or' => [{:city =>"DELHI/NCR"},{:city=>"Noida/NCR"}]).all

Comment: the above query is not working , it is giving an empty array . but in my db data's are there

Comment: I check query, you need check data in db. Execute this:
1)`Customer.where(:gender => "Male").count`
2)`Customer.where(:city => "DELHI/NCR").count`

Answer (score 0):

Notice you don't need both the `where` and `all`.

You can simply write:

```
@customers = Customer.all(:gender => "Male", :city => "DELHI/NCR")
```